# How to Draw Draggable and Resizable rectangle in google map api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to draw a custom rectangle which is resizable and draggable with a close button and 
which is formed with the bounds returned by the query in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a rectangle resizable and dragabble. A little search and some trying would give you what you need.

```
function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5452, -78.5389),
          zoom: 9,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          myOptions);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(44.490, -78.649),
          new google.maps.LatLng(44.599, -78.443)
        );

        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          bounds: bounds,
          editable: true
        });

        rectangle.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't draggable (just resizable), also no close button. I'm also searching for a way to drag rectangle (like on Yelp search).

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you need to add is "draggable: true" in rectangle options.

So, it should be something like this;

```
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: bounds,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true
    });
```

This will make the rectangle resizable and draggable. Also in the body of the page create one button.

```
<body >
<button onclick="remove()">Close</button>      
</body>
```

Inside remove function you can write your code to connect to database. You will have to declare the bounds outside initialize() to access it. This link might help you to understand how to connect google maps and MySQL. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3